# Bacula backup on Linux, restore on FreeBSD

Tags: linux, backup, freebsd, bacula

I'd like to migrate my storage server from Linux (Debian) to FreeBSD. Biggest part of this is restoring backups saved on Linux to tape volumes on the newly installed FreeBSD.

Unfortunately I don't have anywhere to test this on at the moment but I'd like to ask you if you're aware of any incompatiblities or Bacula specific settings that should be used to make this as smooth of a process as possible.

Comment: Why not just copy from one server to the other using something like rsync? Are you planning on reusing the existing server to make your new one?

Comment: Yes, that's the case. Even if it was going to be a different machine, restoring from tape would still be faster in my case (LTO4). I'm not looking for alternative solutions - I'm merely interested if anyone is aware of any gotchas or incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bacula volume format is OS- and architecture-independent, so any problems are likely to be caused by OS drivers -- the [manual](http://www.bacula.org/5.2.x-manuals/en/problems/problems/Testing_Your_Tape_Drive.html#SECTION00437000000000000000) recommends to alter specific settings.